# not given .Parameters as an option even though I have using System.Data.SqlClient;

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


namespace Bookstore
{
    public partial class search : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        //Get the connection string from web.config
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BookstoreConnectionString"].ToString();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                FillPage();
            }
        }

        public void FillPage() 
        {
            //Check if the url contains searchString parameter
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["searchString"]))
            {
                string searchString = Request.QueryString["searchString"];
            }
            lblResult.Text = "";

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            // query string with @search variable
            var query = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Name LIKE '%' + @search + '%' OR ItemNumber LIKE '%' + @search + '%' OR Price LIKE '%' + @search + '%' OR Description LIKE '%' + @search + '%' ORDER BY Name";

            try
            {
                SqlCommand search = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

                //placed the search string in the @search variable
                query.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = searchString;

                conn.Open();

                query.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }

        }
```

I am a new programmer trying to learn the basics, patience is appreciated.

I am trying to pass a parameter from the URL into a query string.

In the above code I am trying to use:

```
query.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = searchString;
```

to accomplish this.

My problem is that .Parameters in not being recognized. It has a red squiggly line under it. I have: using System.Data.SqlClient at the top so I'm stumped. I have searched for two days online for a solution but have found nothing. Probably because I don't know the correct search terms for this problem.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks,
Diana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter is available with `SqlCommand` object not with the `string`. So 
instead of `query` just use your `SqlCommand` object i.e. `search`

```
search.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = searchString;
```

Comment: thanks Sachin that worked! Now I have to figure out how to successfully pass the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

`query` is a string.  You can't add parameters to a string.  You have to add parameters to your `SqlCommand` instance `search`:

```
search.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = searchString;
```

or simply:

```
search.Parameters.Add("@search", searchString);
```

Comment: So he should use `search.Parameters.Add` intead. Correct.

Comment: He had already the `SqlCommand`, the name of the variable is `search`. He also used `query.ExecuteNonQuery();` which is the next problem.

Comment: Ahh, I missed that he already instantiated `SqlCommand`.  Updated.

Comment: This post could be improved. I stated in my post that I am a beginning programmer. Also, that I probably did not know the correct terminology to find the answer.  With those two pieces of information you might have deduced that the answer you gave may be too cryptic for me to understand. Which it in fact is.

"You have to create a command." means nothing to me. I do not understand what that means. So this is a non-answer.

Comment: @Diana -- I'm confused by your comment.  Maybe you haven't refreshed your browser?

Comment: @Diana -- Or perhaps you commented on the wrong answer which maybe has since been deleted?  I'm really confused by your comment.  Please consider removing your down vote, as my answer -- which was posted first -- says basically the same thing as the answer you accepted.

Comment: @roryap - yes your edited answer is much more clear.  Your original answer said simply "You have to create a command."  It's very difficult for me to form well considered questions. It took me 2 days of hunting for an answer and 30 minuets of forming my question.  You responded with in 5 seconds of me posting.  My impression is that you did not take the time to read the question and understand my problem in your hast to be the first to answer the question.  The person who actually answered my question may not have been"first" but he was the first to gave me what I was after.

Comment: @Diana -- However you read my intentions, the custom is not to down-vote an answer *after* it has been improved just because it originally was lacking something.  If it's lacking something to begin with, sure, down vote it, and then when the poster addresses that, you should reconsider your down vote.  It was never my intention to be hasty.  I think you're reading too much into it.